# C++ negative array indices

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to loop an array then during each loop I want to loop backwards over the previous 5 elements.

So given this array

```
 int arr[24]={3, 1, 4, 1, 7, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4}
```

and this nested loop

```
 for(int i=0;i<arr.size;i++)
 {
      for(int h=i-5; h<i; h++)
      {
        //things happen
      }
 }
```

So, if i=0, second loop would loop last few elements 4,6,2,6,5.
How could you handle this?

Comment: Why are you not able to do it?

Comment: well when i=0 then then loop nested loop h=i-5 is out of bounds.

Comment: @sashoalm i have changed the title

Comment: The easiest I can think of to have an inline function returning the element in the given index if the index is positive, and returning `array.size -1 + index` if the index is negative.

Comment: initialize i to 5 instead of 0

Comment: @Antwane I need this to process elements arr[0-4] as well though. triple_r solution sounds feasible.

Comment: h isn't out of bounds, arr[h] is. h is a perfectly valid int.

Comment: You have tagged it multi-dimensional array.  is this meant to be an array `int[5][5]` or similar? otherwise it is single dimensional.  Please elaborate.  For that matter, please elaborate on what the function is meant to do, we have answers that assume that it should wrap around, and answers that don't.  We can't actually provide a good answer unless we know exactly what you intend the function to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that:

- You only want to go over previous values (i.e. no wrap around) You
- You don't actually want arr to be a multi-dimensional array as suggested
  by your choice of tags
- You want to include the current `i` in your five values

This is just a small modification to your code that will do (what I think) you are asking:

```
#include <math>
int main()
{
   int arr[24]={3, 1, 4, 1, 7, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4}

   for(int i=0;i<arr.size;i++)
   {
     for(int h = max(i-4, 0); h < i+1; h++)
     {
        //things happen
     }
   }
}
```

note the `h = max(i-4, 0)` and `h < i+1`This will reduce the number of iterations of the inner loop so that it starts from index `0` and loops up through the five values up to and including `i`. (four values and `i`). `h` will always be within bounds.
The case where `i==arr.size` won't be a problem in the inner loop as the outer loop will terminate before that happens (`i` is always within bounds).

**Edit: I saw this comment:**

> I want the first element to consider the last final 5 elements of the array though.

in which case, your loops should look like:

```
 for(int i=0;i<arr.size;i++)
 {
      for(int h=0; h<5; h++)
      {
          int index = (i + arr.size - h) % arr.size;
          //things happen
          //access array with arr[index];
      }
 }
```

This should do what you want:

When `i=0, h=0` `index=(0+24-0)%24` which is `0`. For `h=1` we go one less, `index=(0+24-1)%24 = 23` and so on for the next values of `h`.
The code gets the last 5 values, wrapping round, inclusive of the current value. (so will get `20,21,22,23,0` when `i=0`, `21,22,23,0,1` when `i=1`)

If you want the five before, non-inclusive, then inner loop should be:

```
for(int h=1; h<=5; h++)
```

here is the current output of the loop as it stands:

```
i     0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3 ... 22 22 22 22 22 23 23 23 23 23
h     0  1  2  3  4  0  1  2  3  4  0  1  2  3  4  0  1  2  3  4 ...  0  1  2  3  4  0  1  2  3  4
index 0 23 22 21 20  1  0 23 22 21  2  1  0 23 22  3  2  1  0 23 ... 22 21 20 19 18 23 22 21 20 19
```

Comment: so if i=1. first iteration. index = (0 + 24) % 24;                then index = (1 + 24) % 24;

Comment: how does this help me access arr[24]

Comment: @user3189899 Well, you can't access `arr[24]` as it is out of bounds.  I've added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: This is really good explanation and the first I have understood

Comment: I have one question. How could you reverse the loop so it look 5 elements forward and handled the out of bounds as of ar[19]. something like int index = (i + arr.size +k) % arr.size;

Comment: @user3189899 yes, looks like you've got it. `index =(i+arr.size+h)%arr.size` would do that. (or `k` if you use that instead of `h`)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want it to loop around (don't know why). if so, use modulo:

```
int index = (h + arr.size) % arr.size;
```

Comment: You mean you don't know why userxyz wants it to loop around, or you don't know why you assume that?

Comment: @TonyK I don't know why user3512203 would want to loop around like that. There could very well be valid reason, but I have my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Using the modulo operator.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size; i++)
{
  for (int h = 5; h > 0; h--)
  {
    const int array_length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int index = (i - h + array_length) % array_length; // Use 'sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])' to get the size of the array

    //things happen
  }
}
```

Comment: `index` will be negative, because a negative value modulo a positive value is negative (or zero).

Comment: Yes.. sorry.. cheked it using python, where the result is positive.
An solution would be to use 'abs' value.

Comment: `abs` would give the wrong result. You can add the array size before modulo to force it to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Is using `if` statement not an option?

```
const int array_size = 24;
int arr[array_size] = { 1,3,4,5,...,2 }

 for(int i=0;i<array_size;i++)
 {
      for(int h=i-5; h<i; h++)
      {
        int arr_index = (h >= 0) ? h : (array_size + h);
         //do your things with arr[arr_index]
      }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

you may also start the nested loop with something like:

```
for(int h=i-min(i,5);h<i;++h)
{
}
```

which let you process first 5 cells as well. also, if you are dealing with some kind of signal or image processing consider extending arr to have 29 elements with preceding 5 zeros or whatever value would be suitable, and start the first for-loop with 5th element.

Comment: I want the first element to consider the last final 5 elements of the array though.

Comment: yeah, sorry, i didn't understand it at first. 
However, expending the array to store 5 last cells in the begining as well, in my opinion would be a good idea as well, of course, under the condition, that 24 cells is what are you really dealing with, and you are not limited by the memory space.

Answer (score -2):

Just make an if statement in nested loop. Something like this

```
for( int h = i-5; h < i; h++ )
{
   // do stuff        
   if( i == 0 )
        break;
}
```

Comment: this will just return 0, as opposed to relevant index at the other end of the array?